# How to print numbers from range but exclude a number by a given divisible number

Tags: python

I need to print out the range between 0-50 with the exclusion of numbers divisible by 7.

```
for x in range(0,50):#for loop range beginning 0-50
    if x % 7 == 0:
        print(x)
```

Comment: This code prints numbers that _are_ divisible by 7.  The comparison is backwards.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. So I changed my new range, range(0, 51). But I think I said it wrong. I want to print out the range beginning from 0 through 50. But i would like to exclude out numbers that with multiples of 7.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the number is divisible by using the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html) `%`.

The expression `x % 7` will return the remainder of x divided by 7. If the remainder is *not* zero, then x is *not* divisible by 7, so print the number.

```
for x in range(0, 50):
    if x % 7 != 0:
        print(x)
```

Note that in Python, range(start, end) is [start, end); i.e., your range includes every number from 0 to 49.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. So I changed my new range, range(0, 51). But I think I said it wrong. I want to print out the range beginning from 0 through 50. But i would like to exclude out numbers that with multiples of 7.

Comment: The code I posted does exactly that - it prints every number that's *not* a multiple of 7.